# Ignore child elements using jQuery event delegation

Tags: jquery, events, delegation, event-delegation

I am using the on method to delegate a click event to injected divs. These injected divs will have child divs as well that are positioned outside of their parent div. I am looking to ignore the click event on the child divs but can't seem to figure it out. Here is an example:

**Here is a Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7ULUJ/

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="click_this_one_only">
    click event delegated
    <div id="child1">
        child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div id="child_child">
            child child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$('#container').on('click', '.click_this_one_only', function() {

   alert('you just clicked .' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the event target for the element:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ULUJ/3/

```
$('#container').on('click', '.click_this_one_only', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("click_this_one_only")) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});​
```